# In C#, why do I need to type return when it is heuristically unreachable?

Tags: c#

This simple C# method becomes non compilable when the final return statement is removed.
Why? I would say that the switch is complete and thus the final return is unreachable.

```
private static object Convert(bool? predicate)
{
    switch (predicate)
    {
        case false: return null;
        case true: return null;
        case null: return null;
    }

    return null;
}
```

EDIT: I'm using C# 7.3
That's probably the reason why.

Answer (score 6):

Because the compiler isn't always perfect, and you're using an older compiler. If you use a C# 8.0 compiler: it works exactly as you want.

Answer (score 2):

Marc is correct regarding this being down to the capability of the compiler. If you're stuck on an earlier version of C# and want to declare your intent a little better you can consider throwing an `InvalidOperationException` on the *case that should never happen*;

```
private static object Convert(bool? predicate)
{
    switch (predicate)
    {
        case false: return null;
        case true: return null;
        case null: return null;                
        default: throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}
```